# Rails Json response encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, encoding, respond-to

I've a rails controller that respond_to JSON with a wrong encoding.
The site is correctly setup with UTF-8 encoding and the database as well.
The text in my db is well formatted, but in the JSON response, all special characters are set to \ufffd.
How can I solve the problem?

Comment: How are you getting data out of the database? Does it look OK before you JSON-encode it? Have you set `encoding: utf8` in your `database.yml`?

Comment: yes. the database is utf8, the encoding:utf8 is correct, the string are correctly stored in the db (i double checked them with phpmyadmin). the problem is the way rails encode them with to_json method.

Comment: What version of ruby and rails are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everyone running on Ruby 1.9.x and using MySQL, should use the mysql2 gem.
It forces the use of UTF-8 and converts to/from UTF-8 automatically when needed.

Comment: This did not work for me. I'm running Sqlite and characters are written/read from database correctly, however upon using the to_json method all special characters (such as 'åäöячщ') turns into \ufffd